# Angular speed and normal speed

Tags: kinematics, velocity, rotational-kinematics, speed, displacement

The instantaneous speed of a point along a circular path is given by $v=\omega r$, where $$\omega = \frac{\Delta \theta}{\Delta t},$$ $s=\Delta \theta r$, and $v=s/t$.

However, isn’t the displacement measured as in the following figure?

[image]

The relationship between normal speed $v$ and angular speed $\omega$ is related via arc length $s$. The displacement $d$ above is a straight line, not the arc length. So why is $v=s/t$ when it should be $v=d/t$? Would this not invalidate the equation $v=\omega r$?

Comment: I would suggest you revisit the definitions of average and instantaneous velocity.

Comment: the distance traveled is $s$ and not $d$.

Comment: instantaneous velocity is taken in a time interval so small that displacement and distance can approximately be taken equal to each other. Hope this clears the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> The displacement d above is a straight line, not the arc length.

The point particle travels along the arc length, not along the straight line.

> So why is v=s/t when it should be v=d/t?

If should **not** be d/t. It should be s/t. The value s is the distance travelled and t is the time.

> Would this not invalidate the equation v=ωr?

It *would* if it were correct, but you are wrong to use d/t. So the equation is valid.